# How to access items in a dynamic list?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dynamic-linq

I am trying to figure out how to enumerate the results from a dynamic LINQ `.Select(string selectors)` in .NET 4.5. The dynamic linq comes from the `System.Linq.Dynamic` namespace.

**Edit:** I am also including `System.Linq`.

I have a method that looks like this:

```
    public void SetAaData(List<T> data, List<string> fields)
    {
        if (data == null || data.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        var dynamicObject = data.AsQueryable().Select("new (" + string.Join(", ", fields) + ")");
        _aaData = dynamicObject;
    }
```

If I step through the code, I can examine `dynamicObject` and enumerate it to view the results (which are correct). The problem is that I am now trying to get my unit test to pass for this, and I've been unable to access anything in dynamicObject. The `_aaData` field is defined as the type `dynamic`.

In my test method, I tried this:

```
        var hasDynamicProperties = new MyClass<MyType>();
        dgr.SetAaData(data, fields); // data is a List<MyType>
        Assert.IsTrue(hasDynamicProperties.AaData.Count > 0);
```

When I run this test, I get the following error:

```
MyTestingClass threw exception: 
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery<DynamicClass1>' does not contain a definition for 'Count'
```

So, I tried to cast it to a list:

```
Assert.IsTrue(dgr.AaData.ToList().Count() > 0);
```

Which resulted in the following error:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery<DynamicClass1>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'
```

So, then I looked up `System.Linq.EnumerableQuery<T>` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190116.aspx. I see all that `.Count()` is supposed to be a valid extension method, but it does not work when I try it. In fact, none of the methods from that page work when I try them.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you `using System.Linq` ? You need it, and your code doesn't show it.

Comment: Yes. I am using that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension methods can not be applied to `dynamic` objects as if they were member methods.

`Count()` is an extension method defined in `System.Linq.Queryable`, you can call it directly on your dynamic object:

```
Assert.IsTrue(Queryable.Count(hasDynamicProperties.AaData) > 0)
```

Comment: That is very cool. Is there a way I can expand that to access `hasDynamicProperties[0].aProperty`?

Comment: can you show a example pseudo code? what type is `hasDynamicProperties[0]`?

Comment: I figured it out. `Enumerable.ElementAt(hasDynamicType, 0).AddressCode` where `AddressCode` is one of the fields in the `List<string> fields` that was passed to the set method.