# Passing a variable name dynamically to a function

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, variables, reflection

I have a function like this :

```
myFonction(ref List<string>myList)
```

I would like to call this function with a list name dynamically, like this :

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ComboBox myCombo    =   (ComboBox)sender;    
   myFonction(ref "myList_" +  myCombo.SelectedItem.ToString());    
}
```

Is this possible with C# ?

Is there a way to do this simply please ?

Comment: Can you explain more generally what you need your application to do?  To me this is trying to use .NET against the way it was designed, therefore there is likely a pure solution that will solve your issue.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843572/how-to-access-items-in-a-dynamic-list) Hope i've helped you

Comment: Are you sure the method needs to pass the list by reference?  That's very rarely something that you need, given that the list is a reference type.

Comment: Yes, i need to pass the list by reference in order to modify them in my function.

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni You need to modify the contents of the list, or actually change the *variable* to reference a new list?

Comment: Could you take a step back and talk about why you want to do this, and what it's trying to accomplish.  Chances are this isn't the proper approach, but we don't have enough information to really suggest a proper alternative.

Comment: In my function, i need to read the list content and modify the content.

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni: In that case you don't need to use the `ref` keyword.  Lists are already reference types, so you can pass a handle by value, and all such handles will share the same object.

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni Further back.  Why are you passing the list; what does that list represent; what else is using the lists, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invoke your method by providing its parameters dynamically with use of System.Reflection.

ForExample:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public void myFunction(ref List<string> myList)
    {
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public List<string> list1 { get; set; }
    public List<string> list2 { get; set; }
    public List<string> list3 { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething(int listNumber)
    {
        SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass();

        var parameter = typeof (SomeOtherClass).GetProperty("list" + listNumber).GetValue(this);
        typeof (SomeClass).GetMethod("myFunction").Invoke(someObject, new[] {parameter});
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to invoke `myFonction` using reflection.  It's also unlikely (but possible) that the lists are properties; more likely they're fields.

Comment: This won't work because your properties are declared as `private` while `GetProperty` with 1 argument will search for `public properties` only. To fix, change `private` to `public` or use more `BindingFlags`

Comment: Yes this code exactly may not work, but my purpose here is to tell that the issue above can be resolved by using reflection. Performance issues should be thought also, using reflection may not be appropriate always.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, C# is compiled language, not a script one.
You can use `Dictionary<string, List<string>> _Lists` to keep Lists in given order and pass them to function like

```
myFunction(ref (from _Lists in _Lists where _List.Key == myCombo.SelectedItem.ToString() select _Lists.Value));
```

It's not the best approach, but it should work.

Comment: I don't know why you used a `Dictionary` and use a loop(O(n) operation)? `_Lists[myCombo.SelectedItem.ToString()]` would be enough

Comment: Also note this wouldn't work given that the list is pass by reference

Comment: Whether C# is "compiled" or not is irrelevant. It supports reflection, which accomplishes exactly what he wants to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection. For example, if all of the myList_ variables are private instance variables of a class (like the Form that this even handler is defined in), then you could do something like this:

```
FieldInfo[] fields = MyForm.GetType().GetFields(
                     BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                     BindingFlags.Instance);
```

You'd then have to look for one with a matching name. I think there's a method to lookup a member by name, but I'm not remembering it right now. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Type_methods.aspx for more options.

A more conventional approach would be to create a Dictionary that maps the name to the list object. You could populate this dictionary when the form loads then just call something like:

```
myFonction(dictionary["myList_" +  myCombo.SelectedItem.ToString()]);
```

Of course, you don't have to populate the dictionary by hand: you could use reflection (like I showed above) to fill the dictionary at run-time. Then when you add a new list, you don't have to remember to add it to the dictionary. You could also use the same method to populate the combo box.

Note: I am not suggesting that I necessarily condone what you are doing as a good design principle. That doesn't mean it can't be done. Or done well. Or be reasonable.

EDIT: I just noticed the **ref** in your call (I copied and pasted your code). I can't see any reason to pass the list by reference. In any case, you can't pass it by reference if you are getting it from a dictionary -- again, why are you passing by reference?

Comment: still can't use ref... but one could pass both the dictionary and the key, thus allowing the called method to update the stored value if needed

Comment: @BenVoigt Better would be to create a local, pass *that* in by ref, and then modify the dictionary based on the result of the local after the method call.

Comment: @Jeremy, rather than using `GetFields` and finding the one with the right name, just use `GetField` and pass in the name.  Also, clarifying questions should be posted as comments, not in an answer to the question.

Comment: @Servy: It depends on when the change needs to be visible to other code, callbacks, etc

Comment: @Servy Thanks. I knew there was a method that searched by name, but GetFields was the first I found and was too lazy to look any more :)

Comment: @BenVoigt True; also depends on whether modifying that function's signature is an option.

Comment: I'd also like to take a moment to mention that using reflection like this is a **really, really bad idea** and is indicative of a major design flaw.  It's an answer to the question as asked, but it's not a very good solution that almost certainly shouldn't be used.

Comment: I'm guessing that the OP controls the function. At least I hope no one created a common/library function called *myFonction*.

Comment: Hence, my disclaimer: "Note: I am not suggesting that I necessarily condone what you are doing as a good design principle. That doesn't mean it can't be done. Or done well. Or be reasonable."

Answer (score -3):

You should be able to do this:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ComboBox myCombo = (ComboBox)sender; 
   List<string> myList = new List<string>();
   myList.Add(myCombo.SelectedItem.ToString());
   myFonction(ref myList);    
}
```

Comment: He doesn't want a list with a single value of the selected item, he wants the selected item to choose among N instance fields to be the list used in a method.

Comment: @Servy how do you come to that conclusion? That is not what he asking or showing.

Comment: `myFonction(ref "myList_" +  myCombo.SelectedItem.ToString());` this shows what he's trying

Comment: He's showing how to use a string to get a variable with that as an identifier, and he's tagged it "reflection"...

Comment: He may have tagged it reflection but that is not what he is showing.

Comment: @N4TKD One would need to use reflection to accomplish what he is showing, namely how to access an instance field by a string name.

Comment: @Servy again why do you think he wants to access a instance field with a string name?

Comment: @N4TKD Because he's generating a string that appears to look like a variable name that would house a list, and he's trying to pass that into a method that accepts a list.  Why do you think he's trying to wrap that string as the single value of a list to pass that?  1) I'd think he could figure out how to do that on his own, 2) there'd be no need to tag the question "reflection" if that were the case 3) I'd expect the string to look different were that the case.

Comment: I do not know why he would want to pass a list<string> but it appears from his comment that is what he was trying to do and did not know how to do it in C#. I think he tagged reflection, from his lack of understanding of C# variables.

Comment: @N4TKD That makes far less sense than the interpretation that *every single other person* has made, given that, if our interpretation is correct, it *is* appropriate to tag it reflection.  You also haven't really addressed any of the other points, making your assertion far less likely.

Comment: @Servy do you a solution to post? Or you just comment and down voting? What does passing a argument have to do with reflection?

Comment: @N4TKD The reflection has to do with determining what argument should be passed; he wants to use reflection to get the list that is then passed to the method, but doesn't know how.  There is already an existing answer that shows how to do that, although as per my other comments, a proper solution to the problem would require information the OP has so far not given us as to the larger context of the problem.

Comment: @Servy "The reflection has to do with determining what argument should be passed;" How does he ask this in his existing question?

Comment: @N4TKD Because he's trying to use a string value to get a list, and his function accepts a list.  He wants to know how to get the value of a variable given that he has the string value of the variable name.  Also look at the question title, which makes it clear that he wants to dynamically generate a *variable name* and then get that variable's value.  He's not just dynamically generating the single value of a new list.  If he were, that title would make no sense.

Comment: @Servy I do agree it makes no sense but I think it is what he is showing, I think we can agree to disagree on this.